# insert NA if previous variable is 1 grouped by unique id

Tags: r

I have clinical data that records a patient at three time points with a disease outcome indicated by a binary variable. It looks something like this

```
patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102)
time <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
outcome <- c(0,0,1,NA,0,0,0,1,0) 

Data<- data.frame(patientid=patientid,time=time,outcome=outcome)
Data
```

I want to create an outcome incidence variable. There are two conditions:

1. When a patient is coded a 1, I would like there to be a NA for any time period after for that patient.
2. If a patient has NA at time point 1 then time point 2 and 3 should also be NA.

For the example data it should now look like this:

```
patientid <- c(100,100,100,101,101,101,102,102,102)
time <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
outcome <- c(0,0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,1,NA) 

Data<- data.frame(patientid=patientid,time=time,outcome=outcome)
Data
```

Comment: Is it possible, that there are more then one outcome with value 1 per patientid?

Comment: @Benjamin Krick , maybe you could check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Not the smartest way, but you could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

Data %>% 
  group_by(patientid) %>% 
  mutate(outcome = outcome * (1 - na_if(lag(cumsum(outcome) > 0, default = 0), 1))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  patientid  time outcome
      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1       100     1       0
2       100     2       0
3       100     3       1
4       101     1      NA
5       101     2      NA
6       101     3      NA
7       102     1       0
8       102     2       1
9       102     3      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `group_by()` patientid, then use `purrr:accumulate()` and `ifelse()` here:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

Data%>%
        group_by(patientid)%>%
        mutate(outcome=accumulate(outcome, ~ifelse(.x==1 | is.na(.x), NA, .y)))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   patientid [3]
  patientid  time outcome
      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1       100     1       0
2       100     2       0
3       100     3       1
4       101     1      NA
5       101     2      NA
6       101     3      NA
7       102     1       0
8       102     2       1
9       102     3      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and apply it for each  `patientid`.

```
library(dplyr)

return_outcome <- function(x) {
  if(is.na(first(x))) return(NA)
  else {
    val <- max(which(x == 1))
    if(length(val) && val < length(x)) 
      x[(val + 1):length(x)] <- NA
  }
  x
}


Data %>%
  group_by(patientid) %>%
  mutate(result = return_outcome(outcome)) %>%
  ungroup

#  patientid  time outcome result
#      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1       100     1       0      0
#2       100     2       0      0
#3       100     3       1      1
#4       101     1      NA     NA
#5       101     2       0     NA
#6       101     3       0     NA
#7       102     1       0      0
#8       102     2       1      1
#9       102     3       0     NA
```